# JavaScript: How to pass extra parameters to a callback

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a question which has bugged me for a while now.

Let's say I have the following array:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3]
```

Now I have a function similar to this:

```
function print(num, str) {
    console.log(str + ": " + num);
}
```

Is it possible to call the forEach method and pass a string to it?

```
// how do I pass "str"?
array.forEach(print);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have two options here:

Either you swap the arguments, so that `str` comes first. Then you can use `function.bind` to bind the first arguments of the function:

```
function print(str, num) {
    console.log(str + ": " + num);
}

array.forEach(print.bind(null, 'someStr'));
```

Alternatively, you can also create a new (anonymous) function which simply passes some value to the second argument:

```
array.forEach(function (item) { print(item, 'someStr'); });
```

With ES6 and the arrow functions, this even gets a bit prettier:

```
array.forEach(item => print(item, 'someStr'));
```

Both solutions have a very similar effect in that they create a new function object which is then passed to `forEach`. What makes more sense to you depends on your use cases.

And just as a note: You just need to remember that the callback passed to `forEach` actually takes up to three arguments (the item, the item’s index, and the array itself), so be careful when you pass a function that accepts other additional arguments. You can again use a local function to remedy that.

Comment: For those looking at this, wondering how to get the index as well as a parameter, plus the additional parameter, here you go: 
    array.forEach((item, index) => print(item, index, 'someStr'));
You would also have to add the index parameter to the print function declaration:
    function print(item, index, str) {...

Answer (score 5):

Not in this particular situation. The simple solution here is to use an anonymous function wrapper:

```
array.forEach(function (i) { print(i, str); });
```

If you reversed the parameters to `print`, you could do this a little more elegantly like so:

```
function print(str, num) { .. };

array.forEach(print.bind(null, str));
```

`str` will be bound as the first parameter, any parameters that `forEach` passes when invoking the callback are passed in second, third etc. place.

Comment: FWIW: That second option is sometimes called *partial application* or *currying* (after [Haskell Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry)) in the functional programming world.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];

function print(str, num) {
    console.log(str + ": " + num);
}

var str = 'someString';
array.forEach(print.bind(null, str));
```