# Is JavaScript function.bind() supported in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, function-binding

Here a simple code i'm trying to run in google sheets script.
The purpose is supplying the `foreach` callback function additional parameters.

```
function print(str, num) {
    Logger.log(str + ": " + num);
}

function test()
{
  var array = [1,2,3];
  var str = "Stam";
  //This line has an exception
  // TypeError: Cannot convert null to an object
  array.forEach(print.bind(null, str));
}
test();
```

this code is based on the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406763/javascript-how-to-pass-extra-parameters-to-a-callback).

I know there are other solutions, though i want to understand why this one does not work.

I wounder maybe it is not supported with google sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

At Javascript, when `null` of `bind(null, str)` is used, `this` is used. At Google Apps Script, when `null` is used for `bind(null, str)`, an error occurs like "Cannot convert null to an object". I think that this might be the specification of Google side. I'm not sure whether this is modified in the future update. So as the current workaround, how about using `this` instead of `null`? Or if you want to use `bind(null, str)` like `null` under the strict mode, how about using `{}` instead of `null` like `bind({}, str)`?

By the way, I think that `test();` at the last line of your script can be removed. Because in your case, when `test()` is run at the script editor, `test()` is run 2 times by `test();` at the last line. `test();` at the last line is run as the global.

From above situation, when your script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function print(str, num) {
  Logger.log(str + ": " + num);
}

function test() {
  var array = [1,2,3];
  var str = "Stam";
  array.forEach(print.bind(this, str));
}
```

or you can also modify `test()` of your script as follows. The following `test()` retrieves the same result with above one.

```
function test() {
  var array = [1,2,3];
  var str = "Stam";
  array.forEach(function(e) {print(str, e)});
}
```

#### Result:

When you run `test()` at the script editor, you can see the following result at the log.

```
Stam: 1
Stam: 2
Stam: 3
```

#### Reference:

- [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Exactly my question, and even more. Are you saying that in "pure" JS, when supplying null to the bind(null,str), the bounded function actually get this?

Comment: @OJNSim Thank you for replying. I think it's yes. For example, when `console.log(this)` is put in the function `print()` without the strict mode, you can see it. On the other hand, under the strict mode, when `bind(null,str)` is used, `null` can be seen. But in the current stage, Google Apps Script cannot use the strict mode. If I misunderstood your replying and my comment was not useful, I apologize.